# How can i center a div with the class of "collapse" (Bootstrap)?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Currently i have the following:

[image]

I would like the collapsible cards to be centered under the text and icons.. How would i go about doing that? I have tried using CSS on the div, however nothing seems to make a change in their position?

The code i have so far:

```
<div class="categoryList">

            @result
            @if (result == "")
            {
                foreach (String dataLine in userData)
                {

            <p>
                <a data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapseExample" role="button" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseExample">

                    @dataLine.Split(delimiterChar)[0]

                </a>

                <button class="btn"><i class="fas fa-plus secondaryPlusIcon"></i></button>
                <button class="btn"><i class="far fa-edit secondaryPlusIcon"></i></button>
                <button class="btn"><i class="far fa-trash-alt secondaryPlusIcon"></i></button>


            </p>


                <div class="collapse" id="collapseExample">
                    <div class="card card-body w-25 p-3">

                    </div>
                </div>




                }

            }



        </div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If Kira's answer does not work you could try this as an alternative.

```
<div class="collapse" id="collapseExample">
 <div class="card card-body w-25 p-3 desiredclassname">
  ...
 </div>
</div>
```

CSS code:

```
.desiredclassname{
 margin: auto;
}
```

Hope it helps :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use CSS flexbox to get exact centering

```css
.collapse{
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

There is more info here https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_flexbox.asp

Or, you could wrap it in a `<center>` tag:

```html
<center>
  <div class="collapse" id="collapseExample">
  ...
</center>
```

The center tag is discouraged, however. It could be replaced by

```html
<div style="text-align: center;">
  <div class="collapse" id="collapseExample">
  ...
</div>
```

Hopefully one of these answers helps!

Comment: The center tag worked perfectly. Thank you so much :)

Comment: @SeventhWarhawk no! don't use the center tag: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/center